# Is a one-stator reluctance motor possible?

Tags: electromagnetism

Often when the magnetic field of reluctance is pictured, one sees a "flow" from one stator to another across the rotor.  I'm wondering if it is possible to have a reluctance motor with only one salient stator pole?

Comment: I believe you mean one salient stator pole, not one stator.  Could you edit your question for clarity?

Comment: It looks like having pairs of electromagnets is essential to the operation of the reluctance motor -- in order to complete a "flux" circuit.  I think the answer is no.
https://www.intechopen.com/books/switched-reluctance-motor-concept-control-and-applications/switched-reluctance-motor-topologies-a-comprehensive-review

Comment: If you're still interested in an answer, post a sketch of your proposed motor.  If I'm interpreting your language correctly, at best you'll manage to get a motor that would keep spinning if it were given an initial, external kick.

Answer (score 0):

As far as we know, [magnetic monopoles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_monopole) don't exist. As such, it's impossible for any magnet to have only one pole, so your question is one better suited for theoretical physicists than engineers.

Comment: Hi.  Good point with respect to terminology.  However, my question was directed at having only one stator winding (which itself would have two poles).  I've modified my question accordingly.